# ngRoute/$routeProvider how to keep the views and controllers?

Tags: angularjs

so I've written an app, there is a few routes:
1) one that shows chat messages, users list, etc and is kept up to date via the controller
2) game page
3) help page

it works fine, but when click the link for #/game-page, it actually disposes of the chat view, controller, etc. when I click the link for #/chat, it reloads it, but now has to reload all the views and data, which makes it slow and flickery..

I'd really like to just maybe hide the views for the pages that aren't active, so when I switch between them, its instant and everything is still there.

Can anyone recommend a way forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views are cached, so they are not reloaded. If you want data to persist between changing views then don't attach that data to the scopes of the views but to an outside scope or an object in an outside scope.

The views would still be compiled, though, every time you switch between them. If that's a concern then I suggest to use [ngSwitch](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Answer (score 0):

it's normal behaviour to reload the views and controllers for ngRoute.

probably for your case you could create your own router, catch rout param and hide/show needed bloc with **ng-hide**

Comment: I was hoping there was a more "standard" way to go about that.. If thats the case, what is the best way to go about getting the # parameter of the url to decide what should be shown and hidden?

Comment: @MichaelBaldry, you can setup your `$routeProvider config` to have `reloadOnSearch: false` -- then, inside your controller, you can look at `$location.search() // returns ?query=string as hash`; assign your query value to `$scope`; watch for it in something like a `ng-show`.